# php pdo code to get result in array and extract or slice part of it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Data present in my coupondate column like below**

500 => 24-03-2015,501 => 24-04-2015

I need when user search 500 then it get coupondate column data in variable and extract or slice part from them like below.....and return below result only.

500 => 24-03-2015

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $result = $db->prepare('SELECT coupondate FROM receipt WHERE coupon  = :coupon'); 
        $result->execute(array(':coupon' => "$q"));    
        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $info = array();
        foreach($data as $row) {            
        $generateddate = $row['coupondate'];
        $info[] = array('date' =>$generateddate);
        }
        echo json_encode($info);    
    }
    ?>
```

plz help to implement this ...i dont have any idea how to implement this....or suggest this is possible or not

Comment: What you mean it `get all data in variable`? Means all columns from the table?

Comment: no only coupondate column...sorry i edit my questionn..

Comment: So your code retrieves all the record's instead of single record which is 500. right?

Comment: my code retrives all data like 500 => 24-03-2015,501 => 24-04-2015 but i need only this 500 => 24-03-2015 if i search 500 ...

Comment: is `coupon` holds numeric value ? also in `$q` here? If it numeric value then remove the double quotes around the `$q` .  `$result->execute(array(':coupon' => $q));`

Comment: yes like 500 or 501 etc..

Comment: i removed this from code but not getting output as i want...

Comment: Check the `$q` has right value? echo `$data` is showed all the data's?

Comment: when i run this query in database then it also return complete output....SELECT coupondate  FROM receipt WHERE coupon = 500 then it also return  this output...500 => 24-03-2015,501 => 24-04-2015...are you getting proper output when you debug this as i want....

Comment: This is ridiculous statement . Pls check why it happens like this. I dont think any error in your code.

Comment: but why i am not getting my output as i want....plz try i know you can do this....bcoz stackoverflow is the end of all..

Comment: YOUR database schema is wrong. Your compound column should either be 2 columns or be rows in a separate table. What you are asking may well be achievable but from the information you are giving it is impossible to give an answer.

Comment: Get together with  your college course partners. There's five or six asking similar questions on SO at the moment and they're all related to books, coupons, receipts etc